# How to initialize the iOS app bundle for Xamarin.UITests using an IPA for generic iOS devices?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I have started creating an Xamarin.UITest project for an iOS app. I'm facing a few problems:

1. My *.app* file is created only for a specific device type, e.g. *Debug/device-builds/iphone9.1-10.3/xxIOS.app*. How can I create an IPA for a generic iOS device which is not specific to an iPhone or iPad?
2. What is the best way to initialize an app? I'm using the below code for pointing to my app bundle and initializing the app:

   ```
   public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
   {
       return ConfigureApp
       .iOS
       .AppBundle("/Users/..ProjectName/iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.1-10.3/xxiOS.app")
       .EnableLocalScreenshots()
       .StartApp();
   }
   ```